# Generator function behaving differently on lists and generator expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator, generator

So I wrote this useless generator function that consumes the first 4 elements of an iterator:

```
def f(it):
    for _ in range(2):
        for _, x in zip(range(2), it):
            yield x
```

The following example as I expected:

```
y = (x for x in range(4))
for x in f(y):
    print(x)
0
1
2
3
```

This example puzzles me:

```
for x in f([0, 1, 2, 3]):
    print(x)
0
1
0
1
```

Why are the two outputs different?

Comment: You're iterating through `it` multiple times. For lists, this generates a new iterator, thus starting at the beginning. For generator expressions, it uses the same iterator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are *iterable* but not *iterators*. If you create an iterator from the list before passing it, you'll see the same behaviour as the generator expression:

```
>>> list(f(iter([0, 1, 2, 3])))
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

**Iterators are consumed by iteration**, so when you `zip` the second time you are part-way through the iterator:

```
>>> i = iter([0, 1, 2, 3])
>>> zip(range(2), i)
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
>>> zip(range(2), i)
[(0, 2), (1, 3)]
>>> zip(range(2), i)
[]
```

but when you `zip` the list you start it again, creating a new iterator:

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> zip(range(2), l)
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
>>> zip(range(2), l)
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
>>> zip(range(2), l)
[(0, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because a list isn't an iterator, it is a list.  What is happening in the first case is it is consuming the iterator.  In the second case, it is starting over from the beginning.  You would need to do `iter([0, 1, 2, 3])`.